# How to shift images in emgucv?

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, image-processing, emgucv, affinetransform

I want to shift an image by lets say (100,50) using emgu cv.

In opencv, one can use cv2.warpaffine and pass the shift value using a numpy array.
However I can't find any corresponding wrapper function for the same in emgucv.

Comment: You want to shift the image in which Axis X/Y?What about the remaining areas? Can you show any pictorial representation?

Comment: you can find what you are looking for in the CvInvoke Emgu documentation (http://tinyurl.com/qycm75h) or here - http://tinyurl.com/pm6c4to.